# Renaming levels in multiple factors in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple factors in a dataframe that each contain levels with names "Very long text 1" and "Very long text 2". I want to rename the levels to "1" and "2". I can easily do it for each individual factor with

```
levels(df$factorname1)
[levels(df$factorname1)=="Very long text 1"] <- "1"
```

But it's cumbersome to repeat it for a few hundred factors. Is there a way to rename the level for a range of factors or simply locate "Very long text 1" anywhere in the dataframe and rename it?

Example data:

```
structure(list(Q5.2.01 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"A whole different level\n"), class = "factor"), Q5.2.02 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 2\n"), class = "factor"), 
Q5.2.03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q5.2.04 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "Very long text 2\n"), class = "factor"), 
Q5.2.05 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A whole different level\n", 
"Very long text 2 blablabla\n"), class = "factor"), Q5.2.06 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 2\n"), class = "factor"), 
Q5.2.07 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q5.2.08 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q5.2.09 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 1\n"), class = "factor"), 
Q5.2.10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q5.2.11 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("", "Very long text 2\n"), class = "factor"), 
Q5.2.12 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 2\n"
), class = "factor"), Q5.2.13 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Very long text 1\n"), class = "factor"), Q5.2.14 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 1\n", "Very long text 2\n"
), class = "factor"), Q5.2.15 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Very long text 2\n"), class = "factor"), Q5.2.16 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Very long text 1\n", "Very long text 2\n"
), class = "factor"), respondentID = structure(c(8L, 8L, 
8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("EO13", "EO15", "EO17", "EO19", "EO21", "Eo23", 
"EO23", "EO24"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Q5.2.01", 
"Q5.2.02", "Q5.2.03", "Q5.2.04", "Q5.2.05", "Q5.2.06", "Q5.2.07", 
"Q5.2.08", "Q5.2.09", "Q5.2.10", "Q5.2.11", "Q5.2.12", "Q5.2.13", `"Q5.2.14", "Q5.2.15", "Q5.2.16", "respondentID"), class = "data.frame",` row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `revalue` function from the package `plyr`. (It can also be done with base R, but I like this solution).

Here's an example

```
> DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "E")),
                   V2=factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "E")))
> DF
  V1 V2
1  A  A
2  B  A
3  C  A
4  A  A
5  D  D
6  E  E
```

Now let's assume that the factor level `D` is the one we wish to replace. Then we can use `lapply` to iterate over columns in the data frame (remember to only select the relevant factors), and `revalue` to specify the replacement(s). Wrap everything in `as.data.frame` to convert back to a data frame.

```
> library("plyr")
> as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) { revalue(x, c("D"="YAY")) }))
   V1  V2
1   A   A
2   B   A
3   C   A
4   A   A
5 YAY YAY
6   E   E
```

**Update**

You can restrict attention to factors by adding a subset selection to the data frame

```
as.data.frame(lapply(DF[,sapply(DF, class) == "factor"], function(x) { revalue(x, c("D"="YAY")) }))
```

Comment: Hmm, I can get this to work--and the name of the level does get changed, but I keep getting error messages: "The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Very long text 1". This is even though "Very long text 1" does get changed... Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: I think it might be caused by situations (columns) where the factor level is not present for the given factor. I.e., if I had a factor without the `D` level in my example above. Could you add some example data that throws the error?

Comment: I've added some example data. Please note that this time I got both the "The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Very long text 2" error and "Error in revalue(x, c(`Very long text 2\n` = "2")) : 
  x is not a factor or a character vector. " (that didn't happen before when working with my actual data--not sure why as I simply subset and changed level names). Also, I added a level with a completely different name and one with a slightly different one to the two described above in case that's what's causing problems.

Comment: That is because you should only feed factors to the the function as I wrote above. You can automate this somewhat. See the updated answer.

Comment: You can ignore the warnings from factors where your specific level isn't found. Those are not errors

Comment: I'm still getting errors--this time it's "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default".

Comment: Impossible to help unless you show exactly what you are typing